# Python removing least frequently used elements from a list multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi im trying store elements from one list into another under certain conditions. Say the user inputs more than 8 elements into the list. Then the program should delete the least frequently used elements until the list is 8 elements long.
for example `requests=[1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]#remove 1 since its the lowest frequently used`

In my example:
e.g the user inputs 10 elements = `requests=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
The final list should be: `mylist = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

```
#part of my program im stuck on

 
requests=[1,2,2,4,4,5,5,6,7,8]#10 elements # user will be asked to input numbers into requests list
#in my program requests list is input into the empty mylists varible below
#for this example I filled it in so I didnt have to input all my program
mylist=[1,2,2,4,4,5,5,6,7,8] #This is empty at start of program 

c,least=len(mylist),0
#tried inputtting for loop to loop through and delete until the length of mylist is 8
while len(mylist) > 8:
    for j in requests:
        if requests.count(j) < c:
            c=requests.count(j)
                #removing least common element if multiple are common remove the lowest e.g 1
            least=j      
    print("\nLeast used page: "+str(least)) 
    mylist.remove(least)
    if len(mylist)<=8:
        break
#works if while loop is deleted
print(mylist)
```

It works for 9 elements but if the user ends up inputting something like 14 elements into requests then the program needs to delete the least frequently used.
Im unsure how to have it loop through the list again to delete another least commonly used element.
Any help would be great I want to try doing this using vanilla python and no librarys.

Comment: how is ```1 & 2``` in ```1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10``` the least frequently used?

Comment: do you mean the lowest number?

Comment: @dfx99 the least frequent and the lowest number right?

Comment: Try using the ```filter``` it could easily done using filter

Comment: Why don't just keep the 8 more frequent elements?

Comment: sorry i should of explained it better. 1 and 2 would be the least because its the lowest number. sorry for not explaining it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this works:

```py
a = [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
def LeastFrequentIndex(a):
    y = 0
    z=[]
    b=[]
    for x in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[x] == a[x+1]:
            y+=1
        else:
            z.append(y)
            b.append(a[x])
            y=0
    return a.index(b[z.index(min(z))])
while len(a)>8:
    a.pop(LeastFrequentIndex(a))
print(a)
```